# Output should be String when Condition is right SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

I have a little problem here. I have the following Select

```
SELECT ProjektName, Budget  FROM projekt p1  WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MAX(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
UNION
SELECT ProjektName, Budget   FROM projekt p1  WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MIN(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
```

which delivers this result:

```
Projektname     Budget
projekt1        100000
projekt2        30000
```

But instead of the Value I want to write a string which says something like "this is the max Budget"

Like this:

```
Projektname     Budget
projekt1        This is the max Budget
projekt2        This is the min Budget
```

Searched everywhere but only found solutions for changing the Budget in the Select but not the result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use  Concat, like below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a literal string in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT ProjektName, 'This is the max Budget' AS Budget  
FROM projekt p1  
WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MAX(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
UNION
SELECT ProjektName, 'This is the min Budget' AS Budget   
FROM projekt p1  
WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MIN(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
```

Comment: The first query works if two projects have the same max or min value

Comment: @1010 If you think it's because `UNION` removes duplicates, that's not a problem because the strings are different.

Comment: No. I mean that there can be two projects with the same max value. The OP's query would show both as your first query, but the second won't.

Comment: Oh, right, I always forget about those corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` :

```
SELECT ProjektName, CONCAT ('This ' , Budget , ' is the max Budget') as Budget  FROM projekt p1  WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MAX(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
UNION
SELECT ProjektName, CONCAT ('This ' , Budget , ' is the min Budget') as Budget   FROM projekt p1  WHERE p1.Budget=(
    SELECT MIN(p2.Budget) FROM projekt p2
)
```

Comment: Where does the question say he wants to get the value of `Budget` into the string?

Comment: `MySQL` will cast `Budget` to string implicitly, so i check it with an `int` filed and Casting work fine, but depend on the type of Budget field, maybe you need to cast it to string yourself.